nginx + php on Docker Compose generating 404 error
I'm running into an issue with Docker and nginx, where every request to my server is generating a 404 error with a "File not found" message.
This is my docker compose file:
services:
   nginx:
     build: ./nginx_docker/
     ports:
       - 80:80
       - 443:443
     volumes:
       - ./www/:/var/www/html/
       - ./nginx_docker/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

   php:
     build: ./php_docker/
     expose:
       - 9000
     volumes:
       - ./www/:/var/www/html/
   db:
     image: mariadb
     volumes:
       -    mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
     environment:
       -    MYSQL_DATABASE=local_db
       -    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
volumes:
   mysql-data:


nginx Dockerfile:
FROM nginx
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

php Dockerfile:
FROM php:8.2-fpm
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd && \
    docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-enable mysqli

Any help with the config would be appreciated!

please add your default.conf file to the post
